# How to check if an upload to S3 is in progress?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

tl;dr: Is there any way, given a prefix key, to make a request to S3 to check if a file is currently being uploaded?

---

Okay, so I have a client and server. The client makes a request to the server to get a pre-signed URL. The server acknowledges this request, and generates the presigned URL and returns it. The client uses the presigned URL to start an upload.

A second client comes along. It can see that another client has started an upload and what the key is (by asking the server, which has stored some temporary metadata about the upload request). This second client wants to know the status of the upload: has it completed, is still in progress, etc.

The kink here is that the first client might have disconnected or otherwise halted the upload, possibly unexpectedly and without any way to update the server of the failure to upload. Is there any way for the second client to find out what the status is of the upload? Does S3 store any data that indicates that the file upload started, but failed?

Comment: For multi-part uploads, you can list them using [ListMultipartUploads](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_ListMultipartUploads.html) and [ListParts](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_ListParts.html), though if you're using pre-signed URLs, you are probably using standard single part uploads, which have no mechanism to track abandoned or failed uploads.

Comment: I see, thank you. That's what I figured but I wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something.